# Why onClick Firing Immediately?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to add an event (onclick) to a button using javascript. But it is always firing immediately after I render my component, why ?

Here is my code :

https://codepen.io/luxanletexan/pen/MWqxgLd

```
export default class Sharer {

    static init() {...}

    static shareMobile = () => {
        alert('ok');
    };

    static createBlocks = () => {
        const block = `<button class="share__button btn" onclick="{this.shareMobile}">test</button>`;

        return block;
    }

    static render = (block) => {

        if (block) {
            // document.body.innerHTML += block;
            document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', block);

            this.close();
        }
    };
}
```

I am not using angular or react, just Javascript ES6.

Thanks

I created a function and tried to access it with onclick="{() =>...}" but the problem is the same.

Comment: Could you show more code? How is this class used?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. We're just guessing here. Also, why is everything `static`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, here is my codepen : https://codepen.io/luxanletexan/pen/MWqxgLd Thank you for your help.

Comment: @aroh — That code does not have the behaviour you describe. Nothing happens until I click the button; then it alerts.